# DLAST in Access

Tags: function, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am using `DLAST` to return a specific field value for the last record.  The issue I am having is that the last record isn't always the newest date record.  I need to return the value of a specific field for the newest date record.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `DLookup` directly with an SQL clause:

```
=DLookup("Assy", "L2_AOI1", "[YourDateField] = (Select Max([YourDateField]) From L2_AOI1)")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't depend on `DLast()` to return a value from the "last record" of a table unless you use a query based on the table and indicate how the rows should be ordered.  From the *Application.DLast Method* help topic ...

> **Note**
> If you want to return the first or last record in a set of records (a domain), you should create a query sorted as either
>   ascending or descending and set the **TopValues** property to 1.

If you want to use `DLast()`, create a query and use the query name as the *domain* argument.  For example, with this as *Query1* ...

```sql
SELECT ASSY
FROM L2_AOI1
ORDER BY [your date field];
```

... this should work as the text box's *Control Source* ...

```vb
=DLast("ASSY", "Query1")
```

However, you could use a different query which returns the most recent `ASSY` and use `DLookup` with that query.  For example, with *Query2* ...

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 ASSY
FROM L2_AOI1
ORDER BY [your date field] DESC;
```

```vb
=DLookup("ASSY", "Query2")
```

Either way, include an index on `[your date field]` to optimize performance.